# Not able to split the Http Response

Tags: android, http, arrays, http-post

I am trying to split the response that I got from http posting. The response is a byte array.

I am trying to split this as,

```
String venuesArray[] = text.toString().split("~~~");
for (String venueDetails:venuesArray) {         
       String arr2[] = venueDetails.split("^^^");
}
```

Here I am able to split the venuesArray without any problem, but same thing is not happening with venueDetails. It is not getting splitted.

Any answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ^ character is a special character and needs to be escaped.

In Java, the backslash is also special, so you need an extra escape.

```
String arr2[] = venueDetails.split("\\^\\^\\^");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String venueDetails:venuesArray) {
    String arr2[] = venueDetails.split("\^\^\^");
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If venuesArray  is splitting then, VenuesDetails should also split. Please check once VenuesArray has venues in it. If so,

Try  using Regex  :

```
for (String venueDetails:venuesArray) {
        String arr2[] = venueDetails.split("\\^^^");
}
```

Hope it helps.